# Kivy Buildozer Update Android target API level to 26

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

The current API target level of my is 19,how update at 26 ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit your buildozer.spec file. Uncomment the line `#android.api = 19` and changed it to `android.api = 26`. Open your terminal and type [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51736054/10826159). To find out what appropriate sdk and ndk versions to use for targeting api 26, you can try to read [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Android-SDK-NDK-Information).

Comment: Hello i have resolved but not with this tutorial but thanks.You know how to save a image in kivy with method export to png ?

Comment: I haven't done that before but I've seen [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/kivy-users/mUKKxzTYVRo), [this](https://pythontic.com/app/kivy/camera), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003254/kivy-export-to-png-with-an-arbitrary-scale) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38440323/kivy-export-window-as-png-on-android). And from the kivy docs itself, you only need to use `export_to_png(filename, *args)` method like `MyImageWidget.export_to_png(/sdcard0/Pictures/mypic.png, *args)`. You just have to make sure that the directory path exists.

Comment: Hi Jerome Thx but i not know how use this code and information.